# Limit of an $L^1$ sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

We have functions $f_n\in L^1$ such that $f_n(x)$ tends to some $f(x)$ for almost all $x$. Does this mean that $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$? A necessary condition is $\|f_n\|<M$, is it sufficient?

Comment: Why do you ask? What did you try?

Comment: What about $f_n = n\cdot \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$? We have $f_{n} \to 0$ a.e. and $\|f_{n}\|_1 = 1$, so certainly we don't have $\|f_{n} - 0\|_{1} \to 0$...

Comment: @Theo Buehler: I think it is better to use hints.

Comment: Related (though the title is misleading): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20931/how-to-prove-that-convergence-is-equivalent-to-pointwise-convergence-in-c0-1/20934#20934

Comment: @AD. Oh well, this is a long and ever-ongoing debate and I don't really feel like discussing this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider $L^1(0,1)$, look at $f_n=n\cdot\chi_{(0,1/n)}$ (here $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function on $A$).

1. $f_n\to f$ where $f=...$.
2. $\|f_n\|\le ...$ and $\|f\|=...$

Comment: Indeed, thanks a lot. But we seem to have the weak convergence.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, if $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$ then $(f_n)_{n\ge1}$ has pointwise limit $0$ but $\|f_n\|_1=1$ for every $n$ so $f_n\not\to 0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.